# Can one use CLion macro's in Run/Debug Configurations?

Tags: cmake, arm, gdb, clion

I have added a GDB Remote Debug via CLion to debug my nRF52 chip but in order to debug the gdb needs a symbol (.out) file. This symbol file name changes when the projects file name changes aswell, so I want to add a macro from CMake, such as `${PROJECT_NAME}` or something. I have tried using `$ProjectName$.out` but it looks like CLion does not recognize this. [image].

Does such a feature exist?

Comment: To be clear, where are you trying to use `$ProjectName$.out`? Is this in the CLion GUI somewhere? If so, where? Are you typing this in some command line environment?

Comment: @squareskittles When you go to the top right corner -> edit configurations -> '+' -> GDB Remote Debug. You'll see some text fields like "GDB", 'target remote' args:, Sysroot, etc. So it's in the Run/Debug Configurations GUI Window. If you have selected the GDB Remote Debug template from the templates dropdown, you'll see some text named "Symbol file". Here you can fill in the path to the `.out` file. I believe the GDB uses this symbol file to enable debug, so I'm assuming CLion is calling the path to the gdb.exe with as args the file specified at `Symbol file`. No CLI, just CLion GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, I figured out that you cannot, however it turned out you need CLion EAP (Early Acces program, in order to debug remotely with Embedded GDB Server. One can download it [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/nextversion/).